# How to get predictions from Google maps AutocompleteService with full information about lat and lng?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get predictions from `google.maps.places.AutocompleteService` with function `getPlacePredictions` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletePrediction). I am getting good results but I would like to have extended response containing information about position on map (lat/lng) to be able to draw marker on map. Unfortunately I didn't find good solution and only option that I could find was running function `geocoder.geocode({ placeId })` for each prediction but it is for sure bad approach. Is there any option to extend predictions with position?

Comment: The goal of the autocomplete service is not to show all the predictions on a map and therefore it doesn't return coordinates for each record.

Comment: Thank you @MrUpsidown for answer - so only way is to use geocoder for each of the results? I have problem with geocoder function that I need to fire it multiple times for each result

Comment: That would be a way. Or get place details via the Places API. You might/will run into quota or rate issues. Still, I can't think of why you would need to display all *results* from an autocomplete suggestions results set on the map. That's not what it is meant for.

Comment: @MrUpsidown In general I would like to display 5 locations on map based on search phrase so that's why I used autocomplete and I need position on map for these locations

Comment: I got it, still, that's not what the autocomplete is meant for. And in terms of costs, each "search" will cost you 1 autocomplete query + 5 geocoder requests.

Comment: You're right but that's requirements to have search + display these 5 search results on map. Do you see any other option with google maps service to achieve such goal?

Comment: No I don't. Geocoding requests or place details requests, both based on the place ids. Check the billing page to see which alternative will cost less. Check both API rate limits to be sure you can make 5 requests in a second. Try it. Choose the best option.